# Recursive expression evaluation?

Tags: java, recursion

I wrote this code to recursively evaluate an expression (I'm not done, just working my way up to brackets and parentheses) and I just completed my recursion for the multiplication/division/addition/subtraction. I'm getting a StringOutOfBoundsException for `String sub1 = s.substring(0,i);`, any ideas why? I put some print statements in to check the value of i, and it never came as a value that was not possible for a string index, so what is my problem?

```
    public float evaluate() { 
    String s = expr; 
    float answer = 0;

    //one single variable or just a number
    if(s.contains("+") == false && s.contains("-") == false && s.contains("*") == false && s.contains("/") == false && s.contains("[") == false &&s.contains("]") == false && s.contains("(") == false && s.contains(")") == false){ 
        if(scalars.size() == 0){
            answer = Float.parseFloat(s);
            return answer;
        }
        answer = this.scalars.get(0).value;
        System.out.println("one var/number loop");
        return answer;
    }
    //no parentheses/brackets
    if(s.contains("(") == false && s.contains(")") == false && s.contains("[") == false && s.contains("]") == false && (s.contains("+") == true || s.contains("-") == true || s.contains("*") == true || s.contains("/") == true)){
        answer = evalNoPB(s);
        System.out.println("no parens loop");
        return answer;
    }
    //make compiler happy 
    System.out.println("no loop");
    return 0;
    }
    private float evalNoPB(String s){
        float tempAns = 0;
    if(s.contains("(") == false && s.contains(")") == false && s.contains("[") == false && s.contains("]") == false){
        int i;
        for(i=s.length()-1; i>=0; i--){
            if(s.charAt(i) == '+' || s.charAt(i) == '-'){
                System.out.println(i);
                break; // keep value of i for substrings 
            }
        } if (i<0) { // for loop went through and did not find + or -
            for(i=s.length()-1; i>=0; i--){
                if(s.charAt(i) == '*' || s.charAt(i) == '/'){
                    System.out.println(i);
                    break; // keep value of i for substrings
        }
    }
    }
    String sub1 = s.substring(0,i);
    String sub2 = s.substring(i+1, s.length());

    if(s.charAt(i) == '+'){
        tempAns = evalNoPB(sub1) + evalNoPB(sub2);
    } else if(s.charAt(i) == '-'){
        tempAns = evalNoPB(sub1) - evalNoPB(sub2);
    }else if(s.charAt(i) == '*'){
        tempAns = evalNoPB(sub1) * evalNoPB(sub2);
    }else if (s.charAt(i) == '/'){
        float divisorCheck = evalNoPB(sub2);
        if(divisorCheck!= 0){
        tempAns = evalNoPB(sub1) / evalNoPB(sub2);
        }else { // cannot divide by 0 
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("cannot divide by 0");
        }
}
 }
    return tempAns;
}
```

test

```
Enter the expression, or hit return to quit => 3*3
1 (this is the i value)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String       
index out of range: -1
 at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
 at apps.Expression.evalNoPB(Expression.java:306)
 at apps.Expression.evalNoPB(Expression.java:314)
 at apps.Expression.evaluate(Expression.java:280)
 at apps.Evaluator.main(Evaluator.java:36)
```

Comment: _it never came as a value that was not possible for a string index_ I don't believe you. Post a stack trace. Post and MCVE.

Comment: I added a test case, what do you mean by a stack trace? Sorry I'm new to this

Comment: The message is clearly showing that you used `-1` as an argument.

Comment: And my printed `i` value is saying that `i = 1` so where is the -1 as an argument coming from so I can try to fix it?

Comment: Use a debugger, run through your code.

Comment: What are **scalars** defined in the code?

Comment: `scalars` is an ArrayList containing all scalar variable names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(i=s.length()-1; i>=0; i--){
   if(s.charAt(i) == '*' || s.charAt(i) == '/'){
        System.out.println(i);
        break; // keep value of i for substrings
   }
}
```

In this code segment variable **i** eventually become **-1** and continue to execute.
Even though actual design should be changed, for this step, just adding another **if** statement, just after **for**  statement will solve the situation.

```
if (i < 0) { // for loop went through and did not find + or -
  for (i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (s.charAt(i) == '*' || s.charAt(i) == '/') {
      System.out.println(i);
      break; // keep value of i for substrings
    }
  }
}
if(i < 0)
  return tempAns;
String sub1 = s.substring(0, i);
```

But only this situation, you will have other problems.

Comment: How do you propose I change it? That `if` statement will always return whatever I initialized tempAns to

Comment: As I stated, you should change your overall structure. All efforts go vain if we try to fix everything around, to make it run. Instead, you should read **infix** notation to **prefix** or **postfix** notation conversion. Once you build your **prefix**, your code will be more structured. You should consider changing your code **operator precedence** if you would like to go your actual approach. It seems that you evaluate **+** and **-** operators before ** * ** and **division**.